# Piping Powershell output to a text file

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-2.0

I have the following powershell script that renames files from one location to another with a sequential filename.  Ultimately, these file changes need to be mapped, as in original - new.  Currently, I just have a Write-Host cmdlet and I just copy the cmd windows output into a txt file then run through a python script I wrote to spit out the original and renamed files into an excel file.  I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this in the initial ps script.  Even something tab delimited would be easily copy-pasteable into an excel file.

```
Set-Location -Path "C:\Users\mmcintyre\Desktop\grail_new"
$destLoc = "C:\Users\mmcintyre\Desktop\renamed"
$countRef = [ref] 0
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf -Recurse |
   Copy-Item -WhatIf -Destination { '{0}\{1}.pdf' -f $destLoc,++$countRef.Value }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I am currently using PS 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following outputting old-name/new-name pairs to a TSV file in addition to the copy operation (**PSv3+** syntax):

```
$countRef = [ref] 0
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  $newFullName = '{0}\{1}.pdf' -f $destLoc, ++$countRef.Value
  Copy-Item -WhatIf -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination $newFullName
  [pscustomobject] @{
    Old = $_.FullName
    New = $newFullName
  }
} | Export-Csv -Delimiter "`t" NameMappings.tsv
```

This creates a TSV (tab-separated values) file with columns named `Old` and `New` that contain the old and new full filenames, respectively.

---

**PSv2**: The `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` syntactic sugar for creating custom objects from hashtables is not available in v2, so [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/New-Object) must be used:

```
$countRef = [ref] 0
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  $newFullName = '{0}\{1}.pdf' -f $destLoc, ++$countRef.Value
  Copy-Item -WhatIf -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination $newFullName
  New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
    Old = $_.FullName
    New = $newFullName
  }
} | Export-Csv -Delimiter "`t" NameMappings.tsv
```

**Caveat**: `-Property` accepts a *hashtable*<sup>[1]</sup>
, which means that its key ordering is not guaranteed, so the ordering of properties of the resulting object will typically not reflect the input order - in this case it just *happens to* do so.

If the resulting property order is undesired, you have two options:

- Slow, but convenient: insert a [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) call with the properties in the desired order (e.g., `Select-Object Old, New`).
- More cumbersome: Construct the object empty at first `New-Object PSCustomObject`, and then attach properties one by one in the desired order with individual [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Add-Member) calls.

---

<sup>[1] The PSv3+ `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` syntax is seemingly also hashtable-based, but it is parsed in a way that preserves the key order; i.e., as if you had implicitly used `[ordered] @{ ... }`.</sup>